# Need to create a table in Splunk that is a nested table or has multiple columns

Tags: splunk

I have a working Splunk search that extracts data from an xml file within a logging statement. The search creates a table with 14 columns.  Below is the query that creates this table

```
<sourcetype and other data>..| xmlkv  | rex max_match=0 "\<ns2\:numberCode\>(?P<location>[^\<]+)"| eval Segment1_Origin =  mvindex(location, 7), Segment1_Destination = mvindex(location, 8), Segment2_Origin = mvindex(location, 10), Segment2_Destination = mvindex(location, 11), Segment3_Origin = mvindex(location, 13), Segment3_Destination = mvindex(location, 14)  |  rex max_match=0 "\<carrier\>(?P<carrier>[^\<]+)" | eval Segment1_Carrier =  mvindex(carrier, 0), Segment2_Carrier = mvindex(carrier, 1), Segment3_Carrier = mvindex(carrier, 2) |  rex max_match=0 "\<billingMethod\>(?P<billingMethod>[^\<]+)" | eval Segment1_BillingMethod =  mvindex(billingMethod, 0), Segment2_BillingMethod = mvindex(billingMethod, 1), Segment3_BillingMethod = mvindex(billingMethod, 2) | table purchCostReference, eventType, Segment1_Carrier, Segment1_BillingMethod, Segment1_Origin, Segment1_Destination, Segment2_Carrier, Segment2_BillingMethod, Segment2_Origin, Segment2_Destination, Segment3_Carrier, Segment3_BillingMethod, Segment3_Origin, Segment3_Destination | sort purchCostReference, eventType
```

The table looks like this (all columns not shown because of the size):
[image]

I would like the table to have the table nested by Segments in some way.
[image]

Or like this:
[image]

Is either one of these table designs possible in Splunk?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I created the second instance of a table.  Added a time field. Using these commands, I parsed the values needed in the xml

```
sourcetype... |xmlkv | rex max_match=0 "\<purchasedCostTripSegment\>(?P<segment>[^\<]+)" |eval Segments =  mvrange(1,mvcount(mvindex(segment, 0, 2))+1,1) | rex max_match=0 "\<carrier\>(?P<Carriers>[^\<]+)" | rex max_match=0 "\<billingMethod\>(?P<BillingMethod>[^\<]+)" | rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<origin>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<Origin>\d+)"  | rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<destination>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<Destination>\d+)" | eval Time =_time | convert timeformat="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S" ctime(Time) | table purchCostReference, eventType, Time, Segments, Carriers, BillingMethod, Origin, Destination | sort - Time
```